# pandas datetime is shown as numbers in plot

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have got a datetime variable in pandas dataframe [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFjFZ.png), when I check the dtypes, it shows the right format (datetime) [2], however when I try to plot this variable, it is being plotted as numbers and not datetime [3].

The most surprising is that this variable was working fine till yesterday, I do not know what has change today :( and as the dtype is showing fine, I am clueless what else could go wrong. 
I would highly appreciate your feedback.

thank you,

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFjFZ.png)

```
df.head()
reactive_power  current timeofmeasurement
0   0   0.000   2018-12-12 10:43:41
1   0   0.000   2018-12-12 10:44:32
2   0   1.147   2018-12-12 10:46:16
3   262 1.135   2018-12-12 10:47:30
4   1159    4.989   2018-12-12 10:49:47
```

[2]

---

```
[] df.dtypes
   reactive_power                int64
   current                     float64
   timeofmeasurement    datetime64[ns]
   dtype: object
```

[3]
[[image: current vs timeofmeasurement]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFjFZ.png)

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert your datetime column from string type into datetime type, and then set it as index. I don't have your original code, but something along those lines:

```
#Convert to datetime
df["current timeofmeasurement"] = pd.to_datetime(df["current timeofmeasurement"], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%H:%S")

#Set date as index
df = df.set_index("current timeofmeasurement")

#Then you can plot easily
df.plot()
```